# Unable to change date format for JSON

Tags: 7, entities

I'm having a problem with the date format in Drupal 7. I want that JSON returns only the year in VALUE. But drupal devel renders the full date like `"value":"2018-01-01 00:00:00"`

I tried modifying the database but doesn't seem to work. I googled the problem but it looks like a date core module problem.

The last thing i tried was to modify the template.tpl with this code (according to devel module):

```
  $variables['node']->field_fecha[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
        'value' => format_date(strtotime('now'), 'custom', 'Y', 'UTC'),
        'timezone' => 'UTC',  
        'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
     );
```

But doesn't change anything. And on top of that i looked at DOM an returns this:

```
<span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2018-01-01T00:00:00-03:00">2018</span>
```

I know that i want to display the year only, but it returns it with all the other fields by default: `-01-01T00:00:00-03:00`

I would like if it's posible that the value looks like this:

```
<span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2018">2018</span>
```

I have seen people in forums that could split the values, but they don't explain how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Use the PHP function [substr()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) to grab the four first values. $time = `$variables['node']->field_fecha[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];` `$year = substr($time, 0, 4);`

Comment: Not working. I can print the value but doesnt modify the array ir the dom.